# libGDX change between listeners

Tags: android, menu, libgdx, listener

I have a `libGDX` based game, in which are 2 `Stages` used to store elements. There are ImageButtons and Sprites. All the `Sprites` should call same function, so they are on a `Stage` and `ImageButtons` are on another `Stage`.
I use `MENU` button, to change between listeners.

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if ((keycode == Keys.M) || (keycode == Keys.MENU)) {
       // some code
}
```

There are already two different stages with different buttons. I change between them inside `keyDown` function, like this. This function is inside `keyDown`.

```
ExitButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
 @Override
   public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(dialog);
   pause();
   }
});
```

So I set back listener to default, when other function is called, than main game functions. I would like to make this like a `ToggleButton`, which can change between between listeners. It seems easy, but I cannot use a third type of listeners for this purpose.

Problem is, that isn't any `MENU` button on most newer devices.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @p.streef: How to change `MENU` button to another solution, because this button is device specific.

Comment: have you thought about creating your own button on screen?

Comment: Yes, sure, but what about listener. How to detect, when it is touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer:

From your comments I assume you want to switch between 2 stages, while having a third stage always active. The key here is the `InputMultiplexer` There might be a prettier way to do this, but I think something like this should work:

```
public class ButtonTest implements Screen
{
    public class RedCircle extends Actor
    {
         //just a placeholder, your implementation would probably not use this
    }

    public class BlackCircle extends Actor
    {
        //just a placeholder, your implementation would probably not use this
    }

    InputMultiplexer plexer;
    Stage hudStage;
    Stage redStage;
    Stage blackStage;
    public ButtonTest(Skin skin,List<RedCircle> redCircles, List<BlackCircle> blackCircles)
    {
        hudStage = new Stage();
        redStage = new Stage();
        blackStage = new Stage();
        plexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        plexer.addProcessor(hudStage);
        final TextButton switchButton = new TextButton("switch",skin);
        switchButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
            {
                if(switchButton.isChecked())
                {
                    plexer.removeProcessor(redStage);
                    plexer.addProcessor(blackStage);
                }
                else
                {
                    plexer.addProcessor(redStage);
                    plexer.removeProcessor(blackStage);
                }
                switchButton.setText("this button is clicked");
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });

        for(RedCircle r : redCircles)
            redStage.addActor(r);

        for(BlackCircle b : blackCircles)
            blackStage.addActor(b);


        switchButton.setPosition(0.1f* Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),0.1f*Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        hudStage.addActor(switchButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(plexer);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta)
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        hudStage.act();
        hudStage.draw();
        redStage.act();
        redStage.draw();
        blackStage.act();
        blackStage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        redStage.dispose();
        blackStage.dispose();
        hudStage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is okay, but how could it solve my problem? I use already skins. I don't see solution in it or can't interpret.

Comment: Problem is, that I already can not switch between listeners. For this switch function is `MENU` button, and its `keyDown` function.

Comment: More details: So black shapes are using a type of listeners and red shapes are using another type of listener. Black shape's listener is default on screen, it can switched by MENU button to other type(as shown by code). I would like to make this switch without MENU button.
Figure: http://s23.postimg.org/gtnl9grjf/img123.png

Comment: I think I understand what you want now, check my updated answer.

Comment: Multiplexing inputs. Yes, it sounds much more greater! Thanks, I haven't used this before!